# How to GSON DEserialization ignore null values and keep default

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

I have a JSON Object like

```
{
    "Person":
    {
       "firstname" : null,
       "secondname" : "Baeumer" 
    }
}
```

and my POJO Entity

```
public class Person{
    public String firstname = "";
    public String lastname = "";
}
```

Now, I like to deserialize (JSON -> POJO) and ignore `null` values to keep the default `""`

`GsonBuilder::serializeNulls` does only work the other way round (POJO -> JSON) but does not work with deserialization.

I don't want to write `JsonDeserializers` or `TypeAdapter` for all my entities.

My last solution would be to make everything optional and use a custom OptionalTypeAdapterFactory with custom OptionalAdapter and delegate the value.

Is there any other general solution for this? It would be nice to have something like `GsonBuilder::deSerializeNulls`.